# sqldependency on change not always firing

Tags: vb.net, onchange, sqldependency

Here is my code:

```
 Public Sub RegisterNotification()
    Dim conStr As String = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("sqlConString").ConnectionString
    Dim sqlCommand As String = "SELECT [ID],[Description], [CreateDate], [NoteTypeID] from [note].[Notes]"

    Using con As New SqlConnection(conStr)
        Dim cmd As New SqlCommand(sqlCommand, con)
        If con.State <> System.Data.ConnectionState.Open Then
            con.Open()
        End If
        cmd.Notification = Nothing
        Dim sqlDep As New SqlDependency(cmd)
        AddHandler sqlDep.OnChange, AddressOf sqlDep_OnChange

        Using reader As SqlDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader()
        End Using
    End Using
End Sub

Private Sub sqlDep_OnChange(sender As Object, e As SqlNotificationEventArgs)
    If e.Type = SqlNotificationType.Change Then
        Dim sqlDep As SqlDependency = TryCast(sender, SqlDependency)
        'Dim id
        RemoveHandler sqlDep.OnChange, AddressOf sqlDep_OnChange

        If e.Info = 1 Then


            Dim notificationHub = GlobalHost.ConnectionManager.GetHubContext(Of NotificationHub)()
            notificationHub.Clients.All.notify("added")
            RegisterNotification()
            'GetNotificationList(0, 1)
        End If


    End If
End Sub
```

Global.asax code:

```
 Protected Sub Application_Start()
    Try
        Dim _obj As New DAL.sap.Register
        _obj.Register()
        AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas()
        FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters)
        RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes)
        BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles)
        WebSecurity.InitializeDatabaseConnection("DefaultConnection", "webpages_UserProfile", "UserId", "UserName", True)


        SqlDependency.Start(con)
    Catch ex As Exception

    End Try



End Sub

Protected Sub Session_Start(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
    Try
        Dim NC As New NotificationComponent()            
        NC.RegisterNotification()
    Catch ex As Exception

    End Try

End Sub
Protected Sub Application_End()
    Try
        SqlDependency.Stop(con)
    Catch ex As Exception

    End Try

End Sub
```

Startup code:

```
<Assembly: OwinStartupAttribute(GetType(www.Startup))>
```

Namespace www
Partial Public Class Startup
        Public Sub Configuration(app As IAppBuilder)
            app.MapSignalR()
        End Sub
    End Class
End Namespace

My problem is sqldep_onchange not always firing. Sometimes it works perfectly but sometimes nothing happen. is it a bug or something like that? what i'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like everything is correct, although my VB is extremely rusty, I would try removing the if on the SqlNotificationType and see if that helps, it might be too restricting, I would also make sure that its actually the dependency that is not firing rather an something else swallowing it later on down the chain. Also what happens if your TryCast fails? Since its not in a try it will not throw and your notifications will not fire and your new handler will not be added.

```
Private Sub sqlDep_OnChange(sender As Object, e As SqlNotificationEventArgs)
If e.Type = SqlNotificationType.Change Then
    Dim sqlDep As SqlDependency = TryCast(sender, SqlDependency)
    'Dim id

   Delete --> ***RemoveHandler sqlDep.OnChange, AddressOf sqlDep_OnChange*** <--Delete

    If e.Info = 1 Then


        Dim notificationHub = GlobalHost.ConnectionManager.GetHubContext(Of NotificationHub)()
        notificationHub.Clients.All.notify("added")
        RegisterNotification()
        'GetNotificationList(0, 1)
    End If


End If
```

End Sub

Comment: i've tried what u suggested and nothing happens and it does not throw exception. When i run my application it works great but maybe 10-15 minutes later it does not fire.

Comment: Check to see if you have any handlers registered, one line of code that is nagging at me is the fact that you are immediately removing a handler without checking to see if there is more than one... if you remove the only handler then it will stop firing.

Comment: i'm sorry it's hard to understand english for me. what do u mean? can u give me sample as code? should i remove the line 'remove handler' ?

Comment: Try removing the line I marked for delete, if you find that it is firing more often, do a check to see if there is already a handler before removing.